# Test for either of multiple string inside if statement conditions

Tags: matlab, if-statement, user-input, prompt, strcmp

I want to give the user the option of selecting a file (I know I've currently set it to choose a folder) or inputting numbers manually.

```
prompt = input('Do you want to manually input values or select file? :','s'); 

s2 = {'file','folder'; 'f','choose'};

tf = strcmp(prompt,s2);

if tf >= 1

folder_name = uigetdir
folder_name = uigetdir(start_path)
folder_name = uigetdir(start_path,dialog_title)

else        
    prompt = {'Enter matrix size:','Enter colormap name:'};
    dlg_title = 'Input';
    num_lines = 1;
    defaultans = {'20','hsv'};
    answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans); 
end
```

I want to allow the user to enter the words `file`, `folder`, `f` or `choose` and that to use the folder dialog box in the first part of the `if` statement and if either of these four strings haven't been inputted go to the `else` statement.

Since I'm saving them as strings I'm using `strcmp`. If I run the code and input the word 'folder' I'll get a matrix like:

```
 0     1
 0     0
```

My question is how do I use `strcmp` to say "if any element of the matrix is 1" that the logical output is now 1 and not 0.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
if tf >= 1
```

with

```
if any(tf(:))
```

`tf(:)` returns a column vector of all elements in `tf`, and `any()` checks if there are any values greater than 1.

Comment: Ahhh brilliant! Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `>= 1` is unnecessary as well since `any` will only return `0` or `1`

Comment: @KyleMoffett - Please consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it helped you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [**Ian Riley**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031006/3372061) had suggested, one can also use the following alternatives which rely on the "truthiness" of positive numbers:

[`nnz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html):

```
if nnz(tf)
```

[`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html):

```
if nnz(tf(:))
```

Both methods count nonzero elements in the array.